# Convert curl to python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

This works on my system:

```
curl https://api.serverpilot.io/v1/servers -u KEY
```

I'm trying to convert it to Python and have tried several variations on this code.

```
params = {"u" :KEY}
# params = {"u" :json.dumps(KEY)}

restUrl = "https://api.serverpilot.io/v1/servers"
response = requests.get(restUrl, data=params, headers=headers)
parsed = json.loads(response.content)
print params
print response
print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Did you check the `man curl` manpage? `-u` specifies a *username and password* for authentication. It certainly has nothing to do with what query parameters are sent to the server.

Comment: Note that you could just load a JSON response directly with `response.json()`. No need to use the `json` module here.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This works now with: response = requests.get(restUrl, auth=(CLIENTID, APIKEY))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for curl, you'll see that -u specifies a user. http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl

You can use the verbose options of curl to get a printout of the request being made.

If you checkout the requests documentation, you'll see that it supports different auth methods through the auth keyword parameter. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Essentially, your username (or key code) should not be a GET parameter, it is a different portion of the HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks response = requests.get(restUrl, auth=(CLIENTID, APIKEY))
 works

Answer (score -1):

If you response header is really 'application/json; charset=utf8' (or other charset),

```
assert response.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json; charset=utf8'
```

you can use:

```
parsed = response.json()
```

Comment: This is at most a comment; this is not what the OP is asking about.